# Surf missing in opencv 2.4 for python

Tags: python, opencv, surf

I'm trying to instantiate a SURF object in python using OpenCV as described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#surf) but this happens:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'2.4.0'
>>> cv2.SURF()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SURF'
```

Does anyone know why this happens or if SURF is missing from the Python version of OpenCV?

Comment: That works just fine up to 2.3.2, and the docs say it should work too. What does dir(cv2) show you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a regression which should be fixed in the next library update.

But SURF is not really absent. You still can access it via the generic wrappers:

```
surf_detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SURF")
surf_descriptor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF")
```

---

**Update:** `cv2.SURF()` is restored in OpenCV 2.4.1

Comment: Thanks, that works. What do you mean when you say it's a regression?

Comment: Can someone tell we what is the difference between the two versions (cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SURF") + cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF") vs. cv2.SURF()) expect that the second version is more compact?

Comment: Is it really fixed in 2.4.1? I'm trying to use 2.4.2 and am seeing the same error.

Comment: @AndreyKamaev: I get a segfault when calling `getParams()` on the resulting object; how do I e.g. set `upright` to `True`?